# VMWare上のlinuxの/ディレクトリのサイズを増やしたい

Tags: linux

VMWare workstation上にてCentOS 6.5を動かしています。

/ディレクトリの空き容量が少なくなってきたので、増やしたいと考えています。

`/etc/fstab`の/ディレクトリは

```
UUID=.... /   ext4  defaults  1  1
```

となっています。

`df -k`の実行結果は以下の通りです

```
/dev/sda2  18339256   14325148   3082524  83%  /
```

行った手順は以下の通りです。

1. VMWare上にてメインのHDDの容量を20GBから40GBに増やした
2. CentOSにおいて resize2fsを実行した (`$resize2fs /dev/sda2 38G`)

以下のエラーメッセージが出て増やせないようです。

```
The containing partition (or device) is only 4657920 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 9961472 blocks.
```

/ディレクトリの拡張のため、上記以外に必要な作業はあるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

パーティションテーブルの拡張が必要です。

fdisk などを使って手動でできますが、下記のような手順で initramfs を作りなおして、

```
yum -y install epel-release
yum -y install dracut-modules-growroot
dracut --force --add growroot /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img
```

reboot すると自動的にパーティションテーブルが拡張されるかもしれません。

```
reboot
```

うまく拡張されていれば、resize2fs でファイルシステムが拡張できます。

```
resize2fs /dev/sda2
```

ただ、`/dev/sda2` のようにパーティションを細かく切っている状況で試したことはないので、できないかもしれません。

また、失敗すると起動不可能になったりするので、事前のバックアップをおすすめします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
別途回答に書きましたように、fdiskでパーティションを作り直して解決しました。
お手数おかけいたしました。

Answer (score 2):

すでに解決済みのようですが、同じような問題に遭遇したときのために、 LVM を使ってボリュームを構成しておくと簡単に容量を増やしたりできます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今後のLVMの使用を検討させていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

検索して方法がわかりました。

`fdisk` にてpartitionを一度削除し、partitionを作り直してから `resize2fs` をすればできました。

他サイトの情報ですが、以下のリンクが役立ちました。

[fdiskでDisk容量を拡張する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/2or3/items/501f206a6091a4ce895f)