# VMware ESXi 6.5 Ubuntu のディレクトリサイズを増やす

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

VMware 上に作成したUbuntuのストレージがいっぱいになってきたため拡張したいと考えています。
いくつかのサイトをみるとLVMを拡張する形の説明がありますが、

```
# fdisk -l
Device         Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048       4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096  419428351 419424256  200G Linux filesystem
```

で確認すると、パーティションタイプがLVMではありませんでした。(vgdisplayで表示なし)
Ubuntuインストール時意識しなかったのですが、明示的にパーティションタイプを指定する必要があるのでしょうか。
また、この場合、HDDストレージの拡張を行う方法はありませんでしょうか？
可能性として、既存パーティションタイプをLinux LVMへ変更し、
pvcreate, vgcreate など行えばできるのでしょうか。

過去の質問で似たようなものがありますが、パーティションを一度削除するというのがリスク高そうで試せていません。

[VMWare上のlinuxの/ディレクトリのサイズを増やしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2445/vmware%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%aelinux%e3%81%ae-%e3%83%87%e3%82%a3%e3%83%ac%e3%82%af%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%82%ba%e3%82%92%e5%a2%97%e3%82%84%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この状態でディスクを拡張するのは無理と思います。
また、`sda2`のパーティションタイプを変更するとファイルシステムが無効になるので、実質再フォーマットと同じになります。

ですので、次善策として、ディスク追加して、元のファイルシステムにマウントする方法はいかがでしょうか?
具体的には、

1. 追加ディスクをフォーマットの後、
2. ディスク使用量の多いディレクトリ(例: `/home`, `/var`, `/opt`, 等)の内容を追加ディスクへコピー、
3. コピー元のファイルを削除 (※今のディスクの利用可能量を増やしたい場合)
4. コピー元のディレクトリに追加ディスクをマウント

という感じです。

＃追加ディスクをLVMとして初期化するのもアリです。
＃追加ディスクを`/etc/fstab`に追記する方法や、コピー元のファイルへのアクセスを一時停止させる方法は割愛します。

---

なお、ESXiであれば、スナップショットを取得しておけば、うまくいかなかった際に簡易にディスク追加前の状態に戻せるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。拡張は諦めます。元ディレクトリに追加ディスクをマウントする方向で進めたいと思います。